# Lock Windows Phone 8 from code

Tags: windows-phone-8, locking

Is it possible to lock WP8 via code? I'm thinking of creating a soft lock button for WP8 (a tile when opened locks the phone)

I searched everywhere but couldn't find any info. Any ideas whether if this is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible for an app to lock the screen on WP7 or WP8.